# accessing a private method from another class flutter

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.I have here 3 classes which are the `Login()`, `MainMenu()` which is the screen after already logged, and this `MyDrawer()`which is a drawer of my App.
What I'm trying to do is I want to access the `signOut()` method from `Login()`. How would I do it or what should I do to redesign my code. I've tried below accessing it and it receives and exception  `The method 'call' was called on null.`
This is a code snippet from my full code:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

enum LoginStatus { notSignIn, signIn }

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  LoginStatus _loginStatus = LoginStatus.notSignIn;
  String email, password;
  final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _secureText = true;

  signOut() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _loginStatus = LoginStatus.notSignIn;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    switch (_loginStatus) {
      case LoginStatus.notSignIn:
        return Scaffold(
          
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                    child: Form(
                      key: _key,
            
        break;

      case LoginStatus.signIn:
        return MainMenu();
       
        break;
    }
  }
}


class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  

  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
      )
   )
 }
 
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
    
  final Function onTap;
  final VoidCallback signOut;
 

    MyDrawer(
    {this.onTap,this.signOut
    });

    @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

    
 class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> { 

  signOut() {
    setState(() {
      widget.signOut();
    });
  }

  
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .width * 0.7,
      child: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          height:100,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            children: <Widget>[
               ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app,color: Colors.cyan, size: 30.0),
                 onTap: () {
                 signOut();
                  },
                title: Text("Logout",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18),
              
                ),
              ),
         
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm really stuck with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you receive this message? Why do you pass a signout function to the drawer and the  define a signout function in its state? And you really should consider refactoring your architecture if you want to call the logout function from your drawer. (e.g. checkout the [single responsibility princible](https://medium.com/flutter-community/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-5-principles-of-object-oriented-design-with-dart-f31d62135b7e))

Comment: you should keep your methods separately in a different class file instead of having into a widget class.

Comment: @FrontMobe the `MainMenu()` contains the navigating page after hitting `Login()`. And I want to pass that `signOut` to my drawer where I've made a `ListTile` with  logout button in it. Any suggestion how I'm going to refactor it?

Comment: @OMiShah How would I do that sir? Also I need `setState` if I'll make a different class.